# Function to check if binary tree is BST is always returning true

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have written a recursive program for checking whether a binary tree is a BST.

I have written a base case which is returning `true` or `false`, but I have got confused in recursive case.

This program makes the recursive call but it is not working though I feel its fine.

```
public class BinaryBSTChecker {
    public static boolean isBinaryBST(Node node) {
        if ( node != null) {
            Node leftNode = node.getLeftNode();
            Node rightNode = node.getRightNode();
            int value = node.getValue();

            isBinaryBST(leftNode) ;
            isBinaryBST(rightNode) ;

            boolean leftIsOk = isLeftOK(leftNode , value);
            boolean rightIsOk = isRightOK(rightNode, value);

            return (leftIsOk && rightIsOk);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isLeftOK(Node leftNode, int value) {
        boolean leftOK = false;

        if (leftNode != null) {
            if (leftNode.getValue() < value) {
                leftOK =  true;
            }
        } else {
            leftOK = true;
        }
        return leftOK;
    }

    private static boolean isRightOK(Node rightNode, int value) {
        boolean rightOK = false;

        if (rightNode != null ) {
            if (rightNode.getValue() > value)  {
                rightOK = true;
            }
        } else {
            rightOK = true;
        }
        return rightOK;
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class TestingClient {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Node node = getBSTTree() ;

        System.out.println("------Is Binary BST ?------>"
                           + BinaryBSTChecker.isBinaryBST(node));
    }

    public static Node getBSTTree() {
        Node node = new Node(9);
        Node leftNode = new Node(7);
        Node rightNode = new Node(11);
        Node leftNode2 = new Node(67);
        Node rightNode2 = new Node(8);
        Node leftNode3 = new Node(10);
        Node rightNode3 = new Node(12);

        node.setLeftNode(leftNode);
        node.setRightNode(rightNode);
        leftNode.setLeftNode(leftNode2);
        leftNode.setRightNode(rightNode2);
        rightNode.setLeftNode(leftNode3);
        rightNode.setRightNode(rightNode3);

        return node;
    }
}
```

The above tree isn't a BST as `67 > 7`.

So this should return `false`, but I am getting `true` for this case, and in fact for all cases.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Are you sure to set both children of each node to `null` when creating it?

Comment: What you have there isn't a BST as `67 > 7`.

Comment: yes, so this should return false, but i am getting true for this case. for all the cases i am getting true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value of `isBinaryBST` in the recursive calls, so the function just returns whether the root's children is correct.

But the way you tried to solve the problem fundamentally won't work.

Take this tree:

```
  5
 /
3
 \
  7
```

It's not a valid BST, as `7 > 5`.

There's no way you can check for this by only looking at the direct children.

The recommended approach would be passing in a `min` and `max` to your function, i.e. the signature would be:

```
boolean isBinaryBST(Node node, int min, int max)
```

And simply checking whether the current node's value is between the two (or the node is null) (no need for helper functions), and making the appropriate recursive calls to the children (and remember to check their return values!). The general idea would be: (pseudo-code)

```
return (current node is between min and max)
    && (left subtree is okay, i.e. recursive call with left child)
    && (right subtree is okay, i.e. recursive call with right child)
```

I'll leave the exact details to you to work out.

In the above example, when we get to `7`, `min = 3` and `max = 5`, so we see that `7 > max`, and return `false`.

Comment: Thanks Dukeling :) This really makes sense .

Comment: One more thing DUkeling, lets assume the fundamental logic is right. How do I make the recursive function return something when I have base case returning as well?

Comment: The general idea would be `return (this node is okay) && (left subtree is okay, i.e. recursive call with left child) && (right subtree is okay, i.e. recursive call with right child)`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

why are you returning false at end of public static boolean isBinaryBST(Node node) ?

Return true there and should be ok.

edit:
obviously it was a mistake but i did not take a good look at code.

One more thing here. 
There is only isLeftOK and isRightOk called, but also on left & right nodes but there are also calls

```
isBinaryBST(leftNode) ;
isBinaryBST(rightNode);
```

It seems that results of those are ignored and this is an issue.

return should be sth like:

```
return (leftIsOk && rightIsOk && isBinaryBST(leftNode) && isBinaryBST(rightNode));
```

Comment: thanks @IvayloStrandjev, my bad. I replaced return false with return true bcoz if node is null, its still BSt, but still the code is not working

Comment: This qualifies more as a comment than answer.

Comment: @Santosh I disagree. "Return true at the end of the function" (which is essentially what this answer is saying) is a perfectly valid answer. Although it's a bit low quality while it doesn't explain why this is necessary. And in scenario's like this the code may have multiple issues, thus this is only a partial answer, but I feel it's more a problem of a non-useful question than a non-useful / partial answer.

Comment: @Dukeling, you said it. That's what I meant. It a partial short comment pointing out to a different (though valid) problem rather than answering OPs core question.

Comment: @Santosh Oh wait, you're right. I didn't really look at the code at first. This clearly only affects the empty tree, thus, in all likelihood, this won't fix the problem OP was having.

Comment: You're right guys, i took too short look at the code and this was just edge-case problem. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add null checks or it will go in infinite loop

```
if(leftNode != null)
    isBinaryBST(leftNode) ;
if(rightNode != null)
    isBinaryBST(rightNode) ;

boolean leftIsOk = true;
boolean rightIsOk = true;
if(leftNode != null)
    leftIsOk = isLeftOK(leftNode , value); ;
if(rightNode != null)
    rightIsOk = isRightOK(rightNode, value);
return (leftIsOk && rightIsOk);
```

Comment: Aniket, there is already a null check on the top of isBinaryBST, so these 2 additional null checks not required. thanks